# Show that if $Y$ is another random variable such that $E[X] = E[Y]$ and $V(X) = V(Y)$ then $P(Y \ge a) \le p$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $p \in (0,1)$ and $X$ be a random variable such that $P(X=a) = p, P(X=-b) = 1-p$

Show that if $Y$ is another random variable such that $E[X] = E[Y]$ and $V(X) = V(Y)$ then $P(Y \ge a) \le p$ and that equality holds iff $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution.

I have a hint to use Chebychev's inequality here but I am not quite getting the desired result.

By Chebychev we have $P(\lvert Y - E[Y] \rvert \ge a ) \le \frac{V(Y)}{a^2}$ which we can re-write with $E[X]$ and $V(X)$ but I am still not getting the result.

I can write it as:

$P(Y \ge a) = P( Y - E[X] \ge a - E[X]) \le P( \lvert Y - E[X] \rvert \ge a - E[X]) \le \frac{V(X)}{(a-E[X])^2} = \frac{p(a+b)^2(1-p)}{(a-E[X])^2}$

which would be using Chebychev but this doesnt help since $E[X] = ap - b(1-p)$ and $(a-E[X])^2 = [(1-p)(a+b)]^2$ so if say $p = \frac{1}{2}$ then I just get the last part being equal to $1$ which doesn't insure the original is less than or equal to $p$.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/476573/119261.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a simple solution, make use of the fact that the equalities of mean and variance are not affected by affine transformations to the underlying random variables so
1.)  we can **assume WLOG that** $b=0$. The result trivially holds when $a=0$ (as both r.v.'s have zero mean and zero variance), so assume $a\gt 0$.
2.) we can divide out $a$ and **assume WLOG that** $a =1$

First notice:
$E\big[X^2\big] -E\big[X\big]^2= \operatorname{var}\big(X\big) = \operatorname{var}\big(Y\big)= E\big[Y^2\big] -E\big[Y\big]^2\longrightarrow E\big[X^2\big]= E\big[Y^2\big]$
because $E\big[X\big] = E\big[Y\big]$.  Then

$P\big(Y \geq a)\leq P\big(\vert Y\vert \geq a)= P\big(Y^2 \geq a^2) \leq \frac{E\big[Y^2\big]}{a^2} = E\big[Y^2\big] =  E\big[X^2\big] =p \cdot a^2 = p$
by Markov's Inequality

**addendum**
for avoidance of doubt here are two other basics taken for granted in the above

i)
for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$
$Y':= Y +\lambda$
$P(Y\leq \eta\big) = P(Y'\leq \eta + \lambda\big)$

ii)
for any $c \gt 0$
$Y'':= c\cdot Y'$
$P(Y'\leq \gamma\big) = P(Y''\leq c\gamma\big)$

what the above does with the "WLOG" statements is actually prove the result for the nice case of $Y''$ which gives the result for $Y'$ which gives the result for $Y$.  We 'want' to look at the $Y''$ case because it has an associated $X''$ case where $X''$ is a Bernouli, which is standard form for a binary r.v.

Comment: If $b$ is not zero we have $E[X^2] = a^2p+b^2(1-p)$ then we have $\frac{a^2p+b^2(1-p)}{a^2} = p + \frac{b^2}{a^2}(1-p)$ which is not necessarily less than $p$. So I don't see how we can assume WLOG $b=0$

Comment: invariance under affine transformations is why.... (1.) tells you $X\mapsto X+b$ and $Y\mapsto Y+b$.  Check that the mean and variances are still equal afterward.  A similar idea with (2). And note that these are invertible...

Comment: I showed if $b$ is not zero your statement doesn't necessarily give the result,  I am not talking about $X+b$ we are talking about $b$ being a value that $X$ may take on. We have $P(X=a) = p$ and $P(X=-b) = (1-p)$ if I apply $E[X^2] = E[Y^2]$ as you have shown above with $b$ not being zero the result doesn't immediately follow. Why are you adding $b$? It is a value the random variable takes.

Comment: I put an addendum here that hopefully flushes out your concerns.  The main idea is to use affine transformations so that $X\mapsto \text{Bernouli}$ which is the standard form for a binary r.v. This is in spirit exactly the same for what one would typically do with a Gaussian-- first map it to a standard normal random variable.  Having a random variable in standard form makes life a lot easier.

Comment: You are saying if I translate $X,Y$ into a Bernoulli random variables say $X',Y'$ then I preserve the equality of expectation and variance then can apply Markov's Inequality to get the desired result but since it holds for $Y'$ it will hold for $Y$?

Comment: sort of...  $Y$ may be unbounded so of course we don't map it to a Bernouli, but we do $X\mapsto X' \mapsto X''$ where $X''$ is Bernouli.  So we have $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$, and $(X'',Y'')$.  Applying Markov's Inequality as done in the post: $P\big(Y'' \geq a''\big)\leq P\big(\vert Y''\vert \geq a''\big)\leq p$, working backwards, this implies  $P\big(Y' \geq a')\leq p$ which implies $P\big(Y \geq a)\leq p$ as I point out in the *Addendum*.  This sort of WLOG approach to math is quite common and a technique you should learn, mostly by filling in the details yourself until it's automatic.